# A User has a lock on a version controlled package in Sparx EA. How can I break the lock to allow users to edit the package?

Tags: svn, enterprise-architect

I have rolled out EA in my company. I am having issues with the svn repository for team editing. One of the users checked out a branch on Friday, and had an accident during the weekend and is out of action for a few days. I am sure this is a very common scenario. Because I am a EA admin but not an svn admin we are locked out of the  checked out branch.

Answer (score 2):

1. use a context menu "Package control > File properties" ... to get a
   name of locked file
2. find this file in your local SVN
3. use SVN context menu, "SVN Get Lock" with checked option "Steal the
   locks"
4. then you can release lock in SVN via "Release lock..." or directly
   use Check in EA etc.

Maybe better practice:

1. EA: use a context menu "Package control > File properties" ... to get a
   name of locked file
2. find this file in your local SVN
3. SVN: use SVN context menu, "SVN Get Lock" with checked option "Steal the
   locks"
4. EA: use a context menu "Package control > Re-synch Status With VC Provider" and then you can use Check in EA

Note: I use a Tortoise SVN.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I've followed the instructions. When I checkout I get the following error : `The selected package cannot be checked-out at this time. The assosiated XMI package file is already checked-out.` Any ideas?

Comment: Was "Steal the locks" operation successful? And, after this operation is package already checked out by you. So, try this steps: steal the lock > check in > check out

Answer (score 0):

If by "lock" you mean "checkout" ("lock" has a different meaning in EA), then you can't. An EA admin is not able to check in or undo checkout for another user. This is because these operations require you to log into the version control repository.

If you are sure that any changes the user has made in their checked-out version can safely be overwritten, a workaround is to switch off version control for the package or make a copy and check that in as a separate version-controlled package.

If you do this, be very careful to take a backup first because there will most likely be problems when the first user returns.

Answer (score 0):

Is the locked Package visible in --> Project --> Security --> Manage Locks?

Either it is group or user-locked. As you are admin you can unlock packages..